# inserting a specific url to the javascript function using coldfusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

Here I am trying to do a kind of weird thing, Am not sure what goes best here but here it is:

I have external page which is coming through from cfhttp. in that page, i have a soring function and that sorting function calls itself with appending the actual url with it, so it is breaking:

what i am trying is to find out that URL fom the page itself and append it with the url value, i am not sure at this point, will i be able to do it or not, but i am trying and i need your help guys

Here is the code i am trying:

```
<cfset case1 = find('thisUrl',cfhttp.filecontent)>
    <cfdump var="#case1#">
    <cfif case1 NEQ 0>
        <cfset regeneratelink = insert('<cfoutput>#address#</cfoutput>','thisUrl',case1)>
    </cfif>
```

For tis, I am getting an Error:

```
The third parameter (AtPosition) of the function Insert(SubString, InString, AtPosition), which is now equal to 13048, must be less than or equal to the length of the second parameter (String), which is now equal to thisUrl and has a length of 7
```

if the above what i am doing in coldfusion can be done in jquery, i am open for it, just want to make external sorting functionality work...

Answer (score 2):

Your code as written tries to insert into `#Address#` based on the a position found in the string cfhttp.filecontent. The 2 strings are (apparently) not the same - so a URL found in one would not be positionally relevant to the other.

What you may be trying to do is modify the resultant contents of the HTML retrieved by the cfhttp call and replace `thisurl` with `#address#`.  If that is the case you can simply replace it directly like so:

```
<cfset newHTML = replaceNocase(cfhttp.filecontent,'thisURL',Address)/>
```

Note - you don't need the quotes and pound signs inside the function. Keep it clean.

Meanwhile, I'm not sure I'm clear on the end game here. The Javascript in the returned HTML will obviously not run on the server right? Why are you altering it again? Are you outputing the results to a page for a user?

Comment: because the original javascript runs on their own server, and the sorting does not work, it needs to have a complete address, i am just trying to append the address to the thisUrl variable on cfhttp page, i am mixing client adn server but lost how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

(I'm assuming in all of this that 'thisurl' is an actual url and you just gave us sampledata of 'thisurl')>

Okay first, you can't use tags inside strings so this

```
<cfset regeneratelink = insert('<cfoutput>#address#</cfoutput>','thisUrl',case1)>
```

should be this

```
<cfset regeneratelink = insert('#address#','thisUrl',case1)>
```

But even can be this

```
<cfset regeneratelink = insert(address,'thisUrl',case1)>
```

Straight from wiki docs, the format to use the Insert function is this

```
Insert(substring, string, position)
```

So, when you search cfhttp.filecontent for thisURL, you're finding it at position 13,048.

You're then trying to insert the address into the string thisURL as position 13,048 and it only has a length of 7.

So it seems like you actually want to use..

```
<cfset regeneratelink = insert(address, cfhttp.filecontent, case1)>
```

But that will will actually insert the substring into the string at the first character where

```
<cfset regeneratelink = insert(address, cfhttp.filecontent, case1+len('thisurl'))>
```

However, if you're doing all that you can just use replace

```
<cfif find('thisUrl',cfhttp.filecontent)>
  <cfset regeneratelink = Replace(cfhttp.filecontent,'thisUrl','thisurl' & address,"ONE")>
<cfelse>
  <!--- 'thisURL' was not found, do something else? --->
</cfif>
```

Which replaces just the first occurrence.

Comment: i want to add address to the front, you seems to follow my question good, let me try that

Comment: i am trying this `<cfif find('thisUrl',lnk)>
    <cfset lnk = Replace(lnk,'thisUrl',"http://actualurl.com/" & 'thisurl',"ONE")> 
 </cfif>`. but thisUrl is actually a javascript variable on external cfhttp page

Comment: How would doing this help you? You can't run the Javascript on the server. What would you do with it if it succeeded?